# C# Writing to file hangs UI even when using await Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to save a rather large text file when the user hits the save button. It can be up to 30MBs. After pressing the button, I'd like the texbox to display "Saving..." as it's saving the file and when it completes, display "Saved". However I can't get this to work. I've tried using Task.run, await task.Run, and using a background worker. All these options hang the UI until the save completes. The textbox does not display "Saving..." until after it saves and the program is unresponsive until then. How can I fix this?

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            logFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            btnOpenFile.IsEnabled = false;
            btnSave.IsEnabled = false;

            tbText1.Text += "\n\n***Saving...***\n";
            tbText1.ScrollToEnd();

            await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(logFileName, Results.ToString()));

            tbText1.Text += "\n\n***SAVED***\n\n";
            tbText1.ScrollToEnd();

            btnOpenFile.IsEnabled = true;
            btnSave.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: like, await File.WriteAllText(logFileName, Results.ToString())?  This gives an error of "cannot await void".

Comment: What is `Results`? ToString() on it could cause UI to hang

Comment: Feel free to ignore the incorrect advice in the above comment from @ThomasWeller. It makes perfect sense to offload a potentially-lengthy operation involving writing a large amount of data to a file, to a thread pool thread via `Task.Run()`. I/O vs CPU has very little to do with whether to use `Task.Run()` or not; what's important is whether you want the UI thread to block or not while the operation is in progress (obviously, you do not in this case).

Comment: That said, the code you posted wouldn't block the UI. Other than the fact that you fail to check the value returned by `ShowDialog()` (i.e. even if the user cancels the dialog, you're still going to try to save the file), it seems "reasonable" to me. Post a proper [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @МаксимКошевой: _"What is Results? ToString() on it could cause UI to hang"_ -- the code you're asking about isn't executed in the UI thread, so it can't cause the UI to hang. The `Results.ToString()` won't be evaluated until the anonymous method delegate passed to the `Task.Run()` method is actually invoked, executing the code in a thread pool thread.

Comment: @PererDuniho you are correct, this code would be executed in a new thread, but I can see no other reason why UI should hand there other than `Results.ToString()` call. I don't know why exactly this might happen tho. We'll need to wait for OP to tells us about what `Result` is

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Results is a StringBuilder that stores the text of a large CSV file which I am trying to save.

Comment: It was the Results.ToString() that is hanging the UI. Even if I take out the File.WriteAllText and just have  var s = Results.ToString(), it hangs. I will look into this and post a different question if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is with `Results.ToString()`.

I tried to reproduce the issue with this code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 1; i < 40536; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(new string('a', i));
        }
    }

    readonly StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int tickNumber = 0;

    private void sync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        stringBuilder.ToString();
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private async void async_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Enabled = false;
        await Task.Run(() => stringBuilder.ToString());
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tickNumber %= 50;
        tickNumber++;
        label1.Text = new string('.', tickNumber);
    }
}
```

But it works as expected:

[image]

Sometimes UI hands for a little bit though. Is this what are you talking about?

Try moving code that generates contents for `StringBuilder` inside the task (so this `StringBuilder` only exists in background thread)

Comment: Results.ToString was hanging the UI. Also the tbText1.Text += ".." takes forever if the textbox already contains a very large string. Instead of displaying the "Saving..." in the text box with the large string, I moved it t to a status bar. It no longer hangs the UI.